# Reflected XSS: Why must attack payload be reflected to victim's browser?

Tags: javascript, html, http, security, xss

As far as I understand, this is the flow in reflected XSS:

1. User clicks on a malicious link, submits a malicious form, or visits a malicious site
2. The above action leads to a malicious script running, which tells the browser to send a HTTP request to another server with the attack payload as a parameter in the URI
3. The receiving server processes the URI, which in certain cases means the payload is sent back to the user's browser
4. Cases where payload is sent back to user's browser include for example:

   1. When error messages of not finding resource is reported by browser
   2. When browser wants to report search results
5. The browser then executes the attack payload

**My Question**

- Why can't the payload be such that the receiving server sends whatever the hacker wants, directly to hacker? I.e. why does it need to be reflected back to user's browser?

I have a suspicion, that it is because the browser might be authenticated (logged in) on server. Thus, only if the browser executes the payload, will the hacker get a hold of that specific user's sensitive/restricted account information.

Answer (score 1):

The code has to execute *somewhere*.

It is much easier to trigger arbitrary code execution by sneaking bad data into the user's browser (because it expects to receive HTML with JS mixed in with it) then it is to trigger it on the server.

If it was triggered on the server instead, then it wouldn't be an XSS attack.

(SQL Injection is an example of code execution attacks on a server).

> I have a suspicion, that it is because the browser might be
>   authenticated (logged in) on server. Thus, only if the browser
>   executes the payload, will the hacker get a hold of that specific
>   user's sensitive/restricted account information.

That's why XSS is useful to attackers (otherwise they could just make the HTTP requests from their own browser).

Comment: Thanks Quentin. I guess the `same-origin policy` (SOP) would prevent HTTP read requests from their own browser (EDIT: Own browser, meaning from cross-origin script). To my understanding XSS is done to circumvent SOP, because with XSS the payload is executed by a script from the same origin as the victim server. Is that correct?

Comment: Second follow-up question: Given a user which is authenticated on his bank and that session is still live in user's cookies. Then, isn't a case where an evil script executes a malicious command right away (like transfer money), an example of Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF)? So, with CSRF the malicious code does not need to be reflected back to browser again (thus one step less).